# How to use custom promise for upload in dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Is there a way to use a custom promise to upload the files instead of specifying the url in dropzonejs?

I have to use an SDK that allow me to upload a file calling a js method, I can't specify an URL directly in dropzonejs options.

I thought it would be possible to overwrite the uploadFile method but I can't find a way...

Hope there's a solution for that.

thank you

Comment: your question doesn't even make sense "custom promise" .. "specifying the url" ? can you elaborate more.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention dropzonejs.

My idea is to replace the post call done by dropzonejs in uploadFile method with my code, because I need to call mySDK.uploadFile method instead of pass a uri in the dropzonejs options.
Is it clear enough?

Comment: dropzone only support url posting. It is relatively easy to create a div to be a drop area for files. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop . If you use react then there is also react-dropzone which can fulfil what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

So, you can have a JS method to return a Promise inside of which you can do anything you want. Here is an example:

```
const getUrlFromSomeAPI = async() => {
    const result = await thirdPartyCallToGetTheUrl();
    return result;
}

const yourUpload = async () => {
    const urlToUseForUpload = await getUrlFromSomeAPI();
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        doYourTaskToUploadToUrl(urlToUseForUpload)
        .then(()=> {
           return resolve({
             isTaskDone: true
           });
        })
        .catch(()=> {
           return reject({
             isTaskDone: false
           });
        });
    });
}
```

**NOTE**: if your doYourTaskToUploadToUrl function is returning promise, you can directly use AWAIT pattern there too instead of promise pattern I used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ankur, I know how to use Promises in general but the question is about using them in dropzonejs, sorry, I didn't specify it in my initial post.

In other words I would like to override the default method that do the post call in dropzonejs (I think is uploadFile)